# Upgrading to Azure DevOps Server 2019 and Release Pipeline Fails With VssServiceResponseException Page Not Found Error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

One of our release scripts that worked on TFS 2017 is not working on Azure DevOps 2019 SP 1.

There is a powershell script that runs remote commands on targeted machines (PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1).  It is provided and part of the standard set of available pipeline tasks. You can see it here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellOnTargetMachinesV3/PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1

When it goes to run this script it fails with the following:

> [debug]Unable to create a environment object for given json -
> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line
> 0, position 0.
>
> [debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException:
> Page not found.
>
> [debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue
> type=error;code={"Task_Internal_Error":FaileToFetchResourceProperties};]

There is a recent Microsoft forum post about this issue, but that does not have any good answers. It actually suggests posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you tried open PowerShell and execute the following cmdlet.
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`  on the server?